# XPath Query by Child Attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a very large XML file that I need to extract specific info from. I need to grab all of the node attributes that have associated child elements. Here's an example of how the elements are laid out:

```
<key name="Test Group">
   <key name="Exhibit A">
      <key name="Chicago">
        <key name="server-01-chi">
          <dword name="[SSH2] Port">22</dword>
       </key>
       <key name="server-02-chi">
         <dword name="[SSH2] Port">22</dword>
       </key>
     </key>
  </key>
   <key name="Exhibit B">
      <key name="Denver">
        <key name="server-01-den">
          <dword name="[SSH2] Port">22</dword>
       </key>
       <key name="server-02-den">
         <dword name="[SSH2] Port">22</dword>
       </key>
     </key>
  </key>           
</key>
```

In this case I want to grab the server names which are node attributes. So given the above XML I need this output:

```
server-01-chi
server-02-chi
server-01-den
server-02-den
```

Comment: But the element `<key name="Exhibit A">` has 'an associated child element' too, namely it has a child element `<key name="Chicago">` — however, you don't want `"Exhibit A"` value of its `name` attribute in the output. So what is precisely the rule to choose data you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to retrieve all `key` elements having `dword` direct child:

```
//key[dword]/@name
```

Or, get `key` elements that have `name` attribute starting with "server":

```
//key[starts-with(@name, "server")]/@name
```

Or, go through all the `key` parents as well (if the structure is "strict"). For example, if the `name` of test test group is known beforehand:

```
//key[@name = 'Test Group']/key/key/key/@name
```

<sup>All the expressions work for me on the provided sample XML matching the server names.</sup>